# Considerations to take as a UK citizen travelling in Europe?

Tags: europe, safety, uk-citizens

The world and especially Europe is in a lot of trouble politically, socially and economically. You have a lot of people with financial hardship, poverty which will cause an increase in crime. There is also a lot of anger towards people in UK because we are doing better than Europe. Should this make me concerned when travelling in Europe?

I'm not exactly going to be walking around advertising myself by wearing a Union Jack t-shirt. However using English and with a UK passport I won't exactly be able to fully hide my national identity, even speaking a local language.

I had a look at the Foreign Office for the UK and they say to stay increasingly vigilant to the increase in crime and disruption around Europe with riots/protests etc.

Was hoping SE Travel would be able to add any recommendations on dos and don'ts to stay safe in these troubling times.

Comment: "There is also a lot of anger towards people in UK because we are doing better than Europe." Are you sure? I Am an EU citizen and I have always had pity on the Britons ;-)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee - we are suffering but not as much as some Euro countries e.g. Greece, Spain, Italy, Portugal, France .

Comment: This question is full of false presumptions that aren't even close to being true, and thus is not a "real" question because it has no basis. I voted to close for this reason. Travel is not for political discussion.

Comment: He's not trying for a political discussion. Some of his comments may be speculation, but the single question in all of it is - "should this make me concerned while travelling in Eastern Europe" - which is certainly answerable.  I'll agree though that much of the statements of 'fact' are rather questionable, but nothing that can't be tidied up with some editing.

Comment: I agree with Mark. While the statements made are controversial and perhaps the assumptions made incorrect, I think this is a valid question about safety.

Comment: Just as a sort of addendum , do you think me asking a seperate question on the Euro currency still being used in Greece by the Summer would be an acceptable question?

Comment: No. How could anyone predict that?

Comment: I would ask that on http://economics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well if the euro or some countries collapsed fully, then they would go back to their old currencies which could make travelling in those countries either very good or bad

Comment: Of course, but how could anyone on travel.se answer a question about that? No one knows what will happen. It will only gain speculative answers, which are pointless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this; you're going to Eastern Europe, as you mention in another comment.

In Eastern Europe, like in the rest of the EU (including the UK) there are people living in a bit of a recession (some might say quite a big depression).

Like many in the UK, their thoughts are for their families, friends, how to pay their bills, and how to have fun.  They enjoy their weekends, just like you.  And for the most part, they enjoy meeting new people, just like (presumably, since you're travelling) you.

For the most part, people everywhere are just that, people.  Good people.  Most are happy to meet people coming to their country - after all, you're bringing in tourism money.  You're spending in their stores, staying in their hotels, buying their food.  All positive.

And what of those who aren't all buzzy and happy about a foreigner? Mostly, like in the UK, you'll just find them apathetic.

Then finally, you have the minority - the few bad apples. They exist in every country, and if you're unlucky, you may run into them.  You might even upset them.  They *might* even do something bad to you - verbal abuse, robbery, or worse.

This could happen in Eastern Europe, it could happen in London, or it could happen anywhere - and if it does, you're unlucky.

But for the most part, unless you're in a war zone, people are good people, and living their lives just like you, and you'll have a great time, fantastic experiences and want to do and see more.

Of course, there are some things you can do.  If you're doing well financially, don't rub it in. Don't insult their culture, food, land or anything like that. Remember they have history, especially ex-Soviet states can be sensitive about their past.  Don't get too intoxicated and make a fool of yourself.  Funnily enough - all rules that apply back at home too.

Above all - have fun, Eastern Europe is fantastic!

Answer (score 7):

The situation is far better than you are depicting it (or perhaps, how the UK media is depicting it). Despite popular belief, we haven't quite resorted to cannibalism, suspension of human rights and general carnage. It's kind of ironic you should mention this actually, since I've always perceived UK to be much more totalitarian and generally unsafe than pretty much the rest of Europe. You might find it hard to believe, but there aren't CCTVs on every corner in European cities, armed riots are very isolated activities, and police presence is much less than what you are used to in UK, particularly in London.

Comment: I am going to areas in Eastern Europe

Comment: @loosebruce: I have lived in Eastern Europe for 23 years, and with some sane precautions, you are going to be safe. Horror stories on the media are just a bias. Thousands of people go to Eastern Europe each year, and the vast majority of them return unharmed. I'm pretty sure there's a higher chance to be hit by a car in UK than to be a victim of violence in Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't really anything important to know about travelling around Europe. You will be fine.

A lot depends on where you go, how you go there, what you say etc., i.e. "Don't mention the war" ;). This isn't a UK/Germany thing, but when you go to any area that has a lot of strife just under the surface, everyone has to be careful. Remember that the UK is a rich, powerful country and has been involved in military campaigns all over the place. If you go to a pooer country and spout of about things, people could get offended. This is general travel advice.

If you are driving your UK car, people will be able to see the left hand drive, and know you're foreign, so might be a bit quicker to be annoyed, just relax and take it easy.

You may be mistaken for someone from USA.

> There is also a lot of anger towards people in UK because we are doing better than Europe.

I wouldn't quite say this is true. Lots of people in various EU countries would not be envious of the UK, and would not think that the UK is doing better than other countries. Be careful of relying on British media (newspapers/tv/etc.) they tend to have a slightly biased view towards Europe. You are probably not getting the full story. (I once talked to a Briton who thought  the UK takes EU law and goes above and beyond, France doesn't implement it at all, one look at the European Working Time Directive (etc.) will show you that the situation is reversed)